# validation usage in laravel 4

Tags: validation, laravel, laravel-4

I am working with Laravel 4 validation right now. My basic setup is done and tested. I can fill the form in view and submit to controller. I can save all details to database using model. I am having a problem now with validation.

I use Input::get() to capture each of the posted variables in the controller. I read that validation should ideally be done in the model. where am I supposed to invoke the validator? Model or Controller? and how am I supposed to pass the validator the $input? is it an array of all variables posted or am I missing something?

Laravel 4 documentation really fails to illustrate with examples answers to common usage questions.

This is the validator I set up in my model:

```
public static function validate($input) 
     {
        $rules = array(
            # place-holder for validation rules
            'firstname' => 'Required|Min:3|Max:40|Alpha',
            'lastname' => 'Required|Min:3|Max:40|Alpha',
            'email'     => 'Required|Between:3,64|Email|Unique:users',
            'country'       => 'Required',
            'password'  =>'Required|AlphaNum|Between:7,15|Confirmed',
            'password_confirmation'=>'Required|AlphaNum|Between:7,15'

        );

        # validation code
        $validator = Validator::make($input, $rules);

        /*if( $validator->passes() ) {

        } else { 
            # code for validation failure
        }*/
     }
```

controller:

```
public function register()
    {
        /*Create new user if no user with entered email exists. Use validator to ensure all fields are completed*/
        $user = new User;

        /*Handle input in POST*/
        $email = Input::get('email');
        $password = Input::get('password');
        $passwordConfirmed = Input::get('password_confirmation');
        $firstName = Input::get('firstname');
        $lastName = Input::get('lastname');
        $country = Input::get('country');

        $user->email = $email;
        $user->password = Hash::make($password);
        $user->firstname = $firstName;
        $user->lastname = $lastName;
        $user->country = $country;

        //$user->save();


        $this->layout->content = View::make('test');
    }
```

and I've been following [this link](http://laravelbook.com/laravel-input-validation/) so far when it comes to validation. Please help as I am new to this framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the input in the validator, you did not defined it

Use it like

```
$input = Input::all();

$validator = Validator::make($input, $rules);
```

or

```
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
```

and take a look at the forums, this will help you more than that blog: http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=12104

Comment: Should the validation happen in the controller or the model? There is no clear information on this but I would guess the controller given it is logic

Comment: choose what ever suits your app what you are building, but its optional to place it in models, and one thing check out this package https://github.com/laravelbook/ardent, lot of people use it including my self, will save you a lot of time and its powerful

Comment: Thanks got it working from controller. Although recommendations in some blogs state to use it in the model, I decided to go with the controller given it is logic and data should never reach model unless ready for storage.

Comment: thats why i higlighted, it depends on your app, it is just optional to store your validation data in a model, but not required :)